# rotary encoder pin identification

Tags: encoder, rotary

[image]Every datasheet that I have looked at mentions the function of pins A, B and C but no mention of D and E. I'm unsure which one is the push button output and which one is the Ground pin. I'm currently looking at this one: http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/mechanical-rotary-encoders/6234237/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A range of 12mm mechanical encoders available with or without a push switch, ideal for controls for image and sound devices such as audio mixers and electronic instruments.

Wild guess: these two contacts are simply connected to the push switch, if present.

Comment: Not wild at all. The linked picture shows the (green) switch attached to the back of the rotary encoder propper.

Comment: I have added the picture of the particular model I chose. Does this mean I can connect any of the D or E to the Microcontroller? And the other one to the ground?

Comment: well, it's a push switch. So, do whatever you want with that :)

Answer (score 2):

This information is in the datasheet which your (good) supplier has linked on that page.

[image]

*Figure 1. Encoder pinout. (Click to enlarge.)*

Under Electrical Specification on page 194 you can find the encoder pinout. The two pins on the other side are the push-button contacts.

[image]

*Figure 2. (1) Encoder ABC. (2) Push-button pins.*

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't understand what I was looking at. My inexperience with rotary encoders, that's all.